# Como ejecutar una función de mi Componente1 en mi Componente2 en vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, webpack

Tengo 2 componentes ServicioListarComponent y ServicioCrearComponent. Dichos componentes los tengo registrados en mi app.js de la siguiente manera:

```
Vue.component('listar-servicios-component', require('./components/ServicioListarComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('crear-servicio-component', require('./components/ServicioCrearComponent.vue').default);

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

dentro de mi componente ServicioListarComponent tengo la siguiente función:

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.obtenerServicios();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                servicios: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            obtenerServicios: function () {
                let self = this;
                axios.get('obtener-servicios')
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    self.servicios = response.data;
                })
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Y en mi componente ServicioCrearComponent, estoy haciendo un insert y quiero que al insertarse este registro, llame a la función obtenerServicios que tengo en mi ServicioListarComponent. Este es el código de mi ServicioCrearComponent.

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                nombre: '',
                costo: '',
                estatus: '1'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            crearServicio: function () {
                let self = this;
                axios.post('crear-servicio',{
                    'nombre': this.nombre,
                    'costo': this.costo,
                    'estatus': this.estatus
                }).then(function(response) {
                    swal.fire('El servicio ha sido agregado','','success');
                    $('#modalNuevoServicio').modal('hide');
                    self.obtenerServicios();
                }).catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

El self.obtenerServicios(); que tengo en mi componente ServicioCrearComponente no funciona, no encuentra dicha función y no se como llamar a esa función que se encuentra en mi ServicioListarComponent

Comment: Primero crea un componente padre que tenga como hijos a tus 2 componentes y luego en el componente hijo cuando guarde, manda un emit al componente padre y el componente padre a través de "refs" le dices al componente hijo de litsar que consulte de nuevo el servicio para que tenga la data actualizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero crea un componente padre que tenga como hijos estos 2 componentes:

```
<template>
  // aquí pones tus 2 componentes
 <listar-servicios-component ref="list"></listar-servicios-component>
 <crear-servicio-component @update="actualizarLista"></crear-servicio-component>
</template>
```

Obviamente creas el componente y los importas...

Ahora en el script solo tendras un metodo que recibe el emit del hijo (crear-servicio-componen) y al recibir ese emit, lanza el evento del listar a tráves de la referencia que le pusimos al "listar-servicios-component"

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
        },
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        methods: {
            // aqui llamamos al listar del componente que lista
            updateList() {
                 this.$refs.list.obtenerServicios();
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Por ultimo en el componente hijo que crea, luego que termina la promesa, haces el emit para que lo reciba el componente padre:

```
methods: {
            crearServicio: function () {
                let self = this;
                axios.post('crear-servicio',{
                    'nombre': this.nombre,
                    'costo': this.costo,
                    'estatus': this.estatus
                }).then(function(response) {
                    swal.fire('El servicio ha sido agregado','','success');
                    $('#modalNuevoServicio').modal('hide');
                    // aqui mandas el emit al componente padre
                    this.$emit('update', 'actualiza la lista');
                }).catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
            }
        }
```

Eso es todo :D!